# Cell-reusing issue with list view and view cells with custom renderer

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, renderer

I'm trying to display a list view with cells that are rendered with a custom iOS renderer. When scrolling the list, there are nasty overlays (as shown below). I boiled it down to the following lines of code.

The `App` contains a `ListView` with its `ItemsSource` set to a dummy list of all characters from A to Z. The `ItemTemplate` is created with a custom `ItemCell` defined below.

```cs
public class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        MainPage = new ContentPage {
            Content = new ListView {
                ItemsSource = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToCharArray(),
                ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(ItemCell)),
            },
        };
    }
}
```

The `ItemCell` contains a `Label` bound to the list item.

```cs
public class ItemCell: ViewCell
{
    public ItemCell()
    {
        View = new Label();
        View.SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, ".");
    }
}
```

On iOS the `Label` is rendered with the following `FixedLabelRenderer`. It sets a native control represented by a `UILabel` containing the `Element`'s `Text`.

```cs
public class FixedLabelRenderer : ViewRenderer<Label, UILabel>
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        SetNativeControl(new UILabel(RectangleF.Empty) { Text = Element.Text });
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that, apparently, when reusing a cell, the control is not removed, but only a new one is created. So I'm getting the overlays shown in the screenshots below.

[image]
[image]
(Left: before scrolling, Right: after scrolling)

Interestingly this issue doesn't happen with Xamarin.Forms 1.2.3 or 1.3.1, but with 1.3.5 and 1.4.0.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Oh, I found a solution [on the Xamarin Forum](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/107477/#Comment_107477):

```cs
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);

    if (Control == null)
        SetNativeControl(new UILabel());

    if (e.NewElement != null)
        Control.Text = e.NewElement.Text;
}
```

So basically you need to make sure to only create *one* `UILabel` and reuse it afterwards.

Comment: Could you explain more detail?